# Java Array and ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When I try to create an `ArrayList myArrayList` from an array, using `Arrays.asList(myArray)`, I am not getting the `List` of elements in `myArray`. Instead I get list of `Array`.

The size of `myArrayList` is 1 . When I try to do `myArrayList.toArray()`, I am getting a two dimensional array. What to do to get the elements of `myArray` in a list? Is iterating the only option??

Comment: Looks like your `myArray` is a two dimensional array. Have you made sure there are no double braces like `{{"one", "two"}}`?

Comment: @bluish Sorry, I wasn't doing that. I will correct myself. Thanks. @ others Just as Banther said, I was trying it on an int[]. Next time onwards, I will try to post the code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type of `myArray`? You cannot use `Arrays.asList` with an array of primitive type (such as `int[]`). You need to use loop in that case.

Comment: Thanks Banther. I was trying it for an int[] only.

Comment: @Suma this is why posting code in a question is a good idea. It would have reduced a lot of guesswork.

Comment: @JohnB yes, I understand now. Sorry:(

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the asList method is the right method:

```
Integer[] myArray = new Integer[3];
List<Integer> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
System.out.println(myArrayList.size()); // prints 3, as expected
```

The problem may be that you are calling the varargs asList method in such a way that java is interpreting your parameter as the first varargs value (and not as an array of values).

```
Object myArray = new Integer[3];
List<Object> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
System.out.println(myArrayList.size()); // prints 1 - java invoked it as an array of Integer[]
```

To fix this problem, try casting your parameter as `Object[]` to force the varargs invocation, eg:

```
Object myArray = new Integer[3];
List<Object> myArrayList = Arrays.asList((Object[]) myArray); // Note cast here
System.out.println(myArrayList.size()); // prints 3, as desired
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways by which you can achieve it.[3 example of converting array to arraylist and arraylist to array in java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/converting-array-to-arraylist-in-java.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
Object[] myArray = new Object[4]; //change this to whatever object you have
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Object thing : myArray) list.add(thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the generic type in the method call. The following gives me a list of 2 String elements.

```
    String[] strings = new String[]{"1", "2"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.<String>asList(strings);
    System.out.println(list.size());
```